# Unary operator expected

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

SUBJECT="WARNING CPU USAGE HIGH"
TO=gmail id
MESSAGE=/tmp/messages
echo "#######################" > $MESSAGE
echo "CPU statistics as follows.." >> $MESSAGE
mpstat >> $MESSAGE
echo "#######################" >> $MESSAGE
CPU_USAGE=$(top -b -n1 | awk '/^Cpu/ {print $2}' | cut -d. -f1)
[ $CPU_USAGE -gt 85 ] && mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < $MESSAGE`
```

`./cpu.sh: line 11: [: -gt: unary operator expected`
What might be the reason

Comment: Try quoting `$CPU_USAGE`: `[ "$CPU_USAGE" -gt 85 ]`. Also, this is bash. Just do `(( CPU_USAGE > 85 )) && ...`

Comment: You might want to  `rm $MESSAGE` in the end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The problem

The problem is that `CPU_USAGE` ends up as an empty string.  This causes a problem here:

```
[ $CPU_USAGE -gt 85 ]
```

After the shell variable is evaluated, the above becomes:

```
[ -gt 85 ]
```

This fails because the argument before the `-gt` is now missing.

#### The solution

To get a non-empty `CPU_USAGE`, we need to replace:

```
CPU_USAGE=$(top -b -n1 | awk '/^Cpu/ {print $2}' | cut -d. -f1)
```

with:

```
CPU_USAGE=$(top -b -n1 | awk '/^%Cpu/ {print $2}' | cut -d. -f1)
```

where a `%` was added.

#### Quoting

As mentioned above, when `CPU_USAGE` is empty and unquoted, we get the "Unary operator" error:

```
$ CPU_USAGE=""; [ $CPU_USAGE -gt 85 ] && echo yes
bash: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

It is best practice to quote shell variables in situations like this.  If we do quote it, then we get a different error message:

```
$ CPU_USAGE=""; [ "$CPU_USAGE" -gt 85 ] && echo yes
bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

While we still get an error, this error message is at least more informative: it says that `$CPU_USAGE` is not a number.

#### Simplification

The `cut` process is not needed.  We can replace:

```
CPU_USAGE=$(top -b -n1 | awk '/^%Cpu/ {print $2}' | cut -d. -f1)
```

with:

```
CPU_USAGE=$(top -b -n1 | awk -F'[ .]+' '/^%Cpu/ {print $2}')
```

Comment: I have made the necessary changes and the script has executed error free. But the script is unable to send the mail to the respective mail id. Since i am using ubuntu i have installed `apt-get install mailutils`. The mail is sent to `/var/mail/root` instead of the given mail id.

Comment: @darshankrishnaiah I'm glad that helped.   Your `mail` command works fine for me but I am using BSD-mailx.  Unfortunately, I have no experience with GNU's `mailutils`.

Answer (score 4):

Your line

```
top -b -n1 | awk '/^Cpu/ {print $2}' | cut -d. -f1
```

is incorrect. First of all , you're asking AWK to find line starting with `Cpu`, when in fact it starts with `%Cpu`.

Second, you dont need `cut` part. You can use `awk` directly:

```
$ top -b -n1 | awk '/^%Cpu/ {gsub(/\./," ");print $2}'                                             
31
```

---

For future, you can debug scripts with `set -x` at the top of the script after `#!/bin/bash` line. Also , use https://www.shellcheck.net/ which will check the syntax of a shell script