# Dealing with dates in bash

Tags: bash

In the bash script, I want to check if it is the first day of the month.
Now I have:

```
if [ $DAY -eq 1 ]; then
        rclone copy /tmp/$MONTH-$YEAR.tar.gz.gpg /server2/archive
fi
```

and I get an error:

```
[: -eq: unary operator expected
```

I tried many different syntaxes from the web, but I can't succeed. 
Any idea what is wrong?
Ubuntu Server 18.04

Comment: If you put `echo $DAY` before this expression you will see that `$DAY` is not defined at this point, so your expression comes down to `[ -eq 1 ]`. Which is invalid because `-eq` is not a unary operator.

Comment: not defined or empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unary operator expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836788/unary-operator-expected)

Comment: `if ["$DAY" -eq "1" ]; then` will fix the error, but not the problem ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind `-eq` is for numeric comparison but you have 1 quoted `"1"` in which case I think `==` needs to be used instead of `-eq`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Unlike the bash shell keyword `[[`, the shell builtin `[` doesn't observe the `"` characters themselves, as quote removal is performed before the builtin is called. So you can be sure that `-eq 1` and `-eq "1"` both work. They *also* both work with `[[`, but one must actually consult the details of how `[[` works to be sure. On the other hand, [the specific example command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188110/dealing-with-dates-in-bash/1188116?noredirect=1#comment1986101_1188110) `["$DAY" -eq "1" ]` doesn't work because it introduces a new typo: a missing space after `[`.

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for clarifying the intricacies of bash once again!

Comment: darn it I removed the space when adding the " :-(

Answer (score 7):

**Bash does not predefine `DAY`.** As [Jos says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188110/dealing-with-dates-in-bash#comment1986097_1188110), the error message you're getting is the same as the message obtained when it is omitted altogether:

```
ek@Kip:~$ [ -eq 1 ]
-bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

The command `date +%d` outputs the current day of the month. If you want `DAY` to hold that value, you can use:

```
DAY="$(date +%d)"
```

But you can also just place the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) in the `[` command:

```
if [ "$(date +%d)" -eq 1 ]; then
        rclone copy "/tmp/$MONTH-$YEAR.tar.gz.gpg" /server2/archive
fi
```

`date +%d` always outputs two digits, so when it is the first day of the month it outputs `01`, but that is no problem. Arithmetically, `01` is equal to `1`, and you're rightly using `-eq`, which performs numerical comparison (unlike `=`, which performs textual comparison).

You will notice that I have [enclosed](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) `$(date +%d)` in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) in the `[` command. **This prevents [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) and [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting).**

[It is a good idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/11938) always to enclose [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (`"$DAY"`), [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) (`"$((3 + 4))"`), and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) (`"$(date +%d)"` or the less preferred form `` `date +%d` ``) in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) except in the fairly uncommon case that you actually *want* globbing and word splitting to be performed.

If you had written `"$DAY"` originally, instead of `$DAY`, then you would have gotten this error from `[`:

```
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

That error makes much more sense.

I've also enclosed your path, `/tmp/$MONTH-$YEAR.tar.gz.gpg`, which contains the parameter expansions `$MONTH` and `$YEAR`, in double quotes.

Comment: Tnx. When you (and other commentators) mentioned that $DAY doesn't have a value, I noticed that I accidentally delete a block where $DAY, $MONTH and $YEAR were set.